# Apt-get Upgrade Errors

Tags: upgrade, updates

I am having issues upgrading in terminal.  If anyone has suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated!  I am relatively new to linux/ubuntu.  Here is the terminal output:

```
brian_smart@Ubuntu-i7:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade

Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.16.0-49 linux-headers-3.16.0-49-generic
  linux-image-3.16.0-49-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic-lts-utopic linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic
  linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
3 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 63.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 280 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y

Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.16.0-49-generic (3.16.0-49.65~14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic_3.16.0-49.65~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic (3.16.0-49.65~14.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-generic-lts-utopic_3.16.0.49.40_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic-lts-utopic (3.16.0.49.40) over (3.16.0.48.39) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-generic-lts-utopic_3.16.0.49.40_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic-lts-utopic (3.16.0.49.40) over (3.16.0.48.39) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.16.0-49.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-3.16.0-49_3.16.0-49.65~14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.16.0-49 (3.16.0-49.65~14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.16.0-49-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-3.16.0-49-generic_3.16.0-49.65~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.16.0-49-generic (3.16.0-49.65~14.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic_3.16.0.49.40_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic (3.16.0.49.40) over (3.16.0.48.39) ...
Setting up linux-image-3.16.0-49-generic (3.16.0-49.65~14.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-49-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-49-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-49-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.16.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-49-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.16.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-49-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-extlinux 3.16.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-49-generic
P: Checking for EXTLINUX directory... found.
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-49-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-48-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-46-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-63-generic...
P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-62-generic...
P: Updating /boot/extlinux/linux.cfg...
P: Installing debian theme... done.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-49-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-49-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-49-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-63-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-63-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-62-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-62-generic
done
Setting up linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic (3.16.0-49.65~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-49-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-49-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-49-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-49-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-utopic:
 linux-image-generic-lts-utopic depends on linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-lts-utopic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-headers-3.16.0-49 (3.16.0-49.65~14.04.1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Setting up linux-headers-3.16.0-49-generic (3.16.0-49.65~14.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic (3.16.0.49.40) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-lts-utopic:
 linux-generic-lts-utopic depends on linux-image-generic-lts-utopic (= 3.16.0.49.40); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-lts-utopic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-lts-utopic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
brian_smart@Ubuntu-i7:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic (3.16.0-49.65~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-49-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-49-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-49-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-49-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-utopic:
 linux-image-generic-lts-utopic depends on linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-lts-utopic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-lts-utopic:
 linux-generic-lts-utopic depends on linux-image-generic-lts-utopic (= 3.16.0.49.40); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-lts-utopic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-lts-utopic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-49-generic
 linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
 linux-generic-lts-utopic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
brian_smart@Ubuntu-i7:~$
```

Comment: One second and I have found your problem: "No space left on device"

Comment: Can you run `df -h` and edit your question with the output? From just glancing at your question & the terminal output it's obvious you're out of disk space & thus won't have space to install the updates.

Answer (score 2):

This is not caused by lack of diskspace on you normal partition, but is caused by a problem in ubuntu slowly filling up you boot partion with old kernels.

Check this answer: [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your hard drive is full.  Consider upgrading to a larger drive or clearing up some space.  There are many programs out there to aid you, like Bleachbit for instance.